# How do I collect Notes DateTime objects into an Array?

Tags: java, datetime, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm sure it's a rookie's question: I'm struggling with values vs references.

I have to loop through a date period and collect the days into a DateTime Array (= multivalue field in IBM Notes). My code is similar to:

```
public void createFreeslots(Document mydesk) {

    Vector myfreetimes = new Vector();
    try {
        DateTime dtN = (DateTime) mydesk.getItemValue("dsFrom").get(0);
        DateTime dtEnd = (DateTime) mydesk.getItemValue("dsTo").get(0);

        Vector myslot = mydesk.getItemValue("dsPeriod");
        while (dtN.timeDifference(dtEnd) <= 0) {  //endDate not reached?
            collectFreeslots(dtN, myslot, myfreetimes);             
            dtN.adjustDay(1); //increase by one day
        }
        mydesk.replaceItemValue("dsFreeslots", myfreetimes);
        mydesk.save(true);
        dtN.recycle();
        dtEnd.recycle();
        //s.recycle();
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("error in createFreeslots");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void collectFreeslots(DateTime dN, Vector myslot, Vector myfreetimes) {

    if (something with myslot is true) {
        myfreetimes.add(dN);
    } 

}
```

what I want to get is sth like [02/22/2018,02/23/2018,02/24/2018,02/25/2018] ,

but - of course - I got: [02/25/2018,02/25/2018,02/25/2018,02/25/2018]

(not as a string array, but as a datetime object array).

Is there an elegant way to fix this?

Thanks in advance, Uwe

Comment: It looks like `DateTime` represents a mutable type. Since that class doesn't seem to have an actual copy constructor, you would want to use `Session.createDateTime(dtN.toJavaDate())` to create an independent copy (or at least I'd hope it's independent).

Comment: why not put everything inside the while loop

Comment: zakaria: I had it first in that loop, without the extra function: same result. I hoped the function helped me to paste values instead of references.

Comment: M.: yes, I tried sth similar, `s.createDateTime(dN.getLocalTime())` , it works ... but I thought it could be much simpler ;-)

Comment: @UweJ. if you tag the people you are talking to with the at sign as I just did you, they will be notified of your message next time they visit Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for that hint - I will keep it in mind :-)